# How can I show a unique visitor a welcome page only once

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

For the new users that enter my site, would it be possible to redirect them to a landing page? I want this to only happen once in the case of a new unique visitor. Anyone have any software recommendations for this situation? I also don't want this to slow down my site, Thanks a bunch! 
**Using html, JavaScript, and reactjs**

Comment: Of course that's possible. You can use `localStorage` to remember the first time the visitor loaded your page.
`if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) {localStorage.setItem('visited', true); redirectToLandingPage()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies.

First you could define 2 functions that set/get a cookie:

```
function setcookie(name, val) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + val;
}

function getcookie(name) {
    return document.cookie.split(name + "=")[1];
}
```

Then, when a user comes to the site, you could just check for a cookie that they have already been here, and if it isn't there, go to the landing page:

```
if (!getcookie("visited")) {
    setcookie("visited", true);
    // Go to landing page
}
```